# KnockoutJS DRY if statement

Tags: if-statement, knockout.js, dry

Using knockout.js I've run into this problem a couple of times now. It seems that I am doing a lot of repetition for simple if statements that only change a single attribute in a line.

```
<!-- ko foreach: $data.content -->
    <!-- ko if: $index() === 0 -->
        <div class='tab-pane active'>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: $index() !== 0 -->
        <div class='tab-pane'>
    <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

This example is a simple demonstration, but the problem occurs in much more complex lines, which obviously makes it very susceptible for bugs.

Does knockout provide any kind of inline *if* statements, of is there any other way around this code repetition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`css`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html) binding for adding css classes:

```
<!-- ko foreach: $data.content -->
   <div class='tab-pane' data-bind="css: {active: $index() === 0 } "></div>
<!-- /ko -->
```